# Synchronized codes with unexpected outputs

Tags: java, synchronization

The code behind gives an output I can't understand.

I got 2 Integers: count and lock. If I synchronized on "lock"(like it shows in the code), then the output shows that "count" is added as expected,but "lock" is added wrong.
Why did this happen?
I can't change "lock" if I synchronized on it?

Here is the code:

```
public class SynchronizedTest implements Runnable {

    static Integer count = new Integer(0);
    static Integer lock = new Integer(0);
    private int threadIndex = -1;

    public SynchronizedTest(int threadIndex) {
        this.threadIndex = threadIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("in");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            synchronized (SynchronizedTest.lock) {
                count++;
                lock++;
                System.out.println("Thread " + threadIndex + ": " + count);
                System.out.println("Thread " + threadIndex + " lock : " + lock);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("out");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            SynchronizedTest threadTest = new SynchronizedTest(i);
            Thread thread = new Thread(threadTest);
            thread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
in  
in  
in  
in  
in  
Thread 4: 1  
Thread 4 lock : 1  
Thread 0: 2  
Thread 0 lock : 2  
Thread 1: 3  
Thread 3: 4  
Thread 1 lock : 4  
Thread 3 lock : 4  
Thread 2: 5  
Thread 2 lock : 5  
Thread 1: 6  
Thread 1 lock : 6  
Thread 3: 7  
Thread 3 lock : 7  
Thread 4: 8  
Thread 2: 10  
Thread 0: 9  
Thread 2 lock : 10  
Thread 4 lock : 10  
Thread 0 lock : 10  
Thread 1: 11  
Thread 0: 14  
Thread 0 lock : 14  
Thread 2: 13  
Thread 2 lock : 14  
Thread 3: 12  
Thread 3 lock : 14  
Thread 1 lock : 14  
Thread 4: 15  
Thread 4 lock : 15  
Thread 0: 16  
Thread 0 lock : 16  
Thread 2: 17  
Thread 1: 19  
Thread 1 lock : 19  
Thread 3: 18  
Thread 3 lock : 19  
Thread 2 lock : 19  
Thread 4: 20  
Thread 4 lock : 20  
Thread 1: 21  
Thread 1 lock : 21  
Thread 2: 22  
Thread 0: 23  
Thread 2 lock : 23  
Thread 0 lock : 23  
Thread 3: 24  
Thread 3 lock : 24  
Thread 4: 25  
Thread 4 lock : 25  
Thread 1: 26  
Thread 1 lock : 26  
Thread 2: 27  
Thread 3: 29  
Thread 0: 28  
Thread 3 lock : 29  
Thread 2 lock : 29  
Thread 0 lock : 29  
Thread 4: 30  
Thread 4 lock : 30  
Thread 1: 31  
Thread 1 lock : 31  
Thread 3: 32  
Thread 0: 33  
Thread 3 lock : 33  
Thread 0 lock : 33  
Thread 2: 34  
Thread 2 lock : 34  
Thread 4: 35  
Thread 4 lock : 35  
Thread 1: 36  
Thread 1 lock : 36  
Thread 3: 37  
Thread 3 lock : 37  
Thread 2: 39  
Thread 0: 39  
Thread 2 lock : 39  
Thread 0 lock : 39  
Thread 4: 40  
Thread 4 lock : 40  
Thread 1: 41  
Thread 1 lock : 41  
Thread 3: 42  
Thread 0: 43  
Thread 3 lock : 43  
Thread 0 lock : 43  
Thread 2: 44  
Thread 2 lock : 44  
Thread 4: 45  
Thread 4 lock : 45  
Thread 1: 47  
Thread 2: 49  
Thread 2 lock : 49  
Thread 0: 48  
Thread 3: 47  
Thread 3 lock : 49  
out  
Thread 0 lock : 49  
out  
out  
Thread 1 lock : 49  
out  
Thread 4: 50  
Thread 4 lock : 50  
out
```

Comment: You can't synchronize on `lock`, since you're changing it (and `Integer` being immutable, you're actually creating new `lock` objects constantly). Lock objects are usually of the form `private final Object lock = new Object();`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the same lock, since you are changing Integer, a new object is being created each time you are increment the lock, just use a new object and do not change.